# Vue 2 Component not calling main instance function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Okay, this web app I am "still" trying to make is taking longer than I expected and I still don't get some stuff about Vue 2.

For example, I have a componenent that renders in the main Vue instance and I `$emit` a function inside the componenet. Of course, the "inside" function is working but not the "main" one:

This is the component file **PropertyHouseComponent.vue**:

```
<template>
    <fieldset class="form-group col-md">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input
                class="form-check-input"
                type="checkbox"
                id="house"
                name="house"
                v-model="data"
                @click="callFunc">
            <label
                for="house"
                class="form-check-label"
            >House</label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</template>

<script>
    module.exports = {
        props: {
            value: {
                type: Boolean,
                required: false
            }
        },
        data: function() {
            return {
                data: false
            }
        },
        created: function() {
            if(this.value) {
                this.data = this.value;
            }
        },
        methods: {
            callFunc: function() { <-- this method is being called correctly
                this.$emit('toggleHouse', this.data);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I've also tried with `this.$parent.$emit('toggleHouse')` and it's the same and by using instead of `@click="callFunc"`:

```
watch: {
    data: function(value) {
        this.$emit('toggleHouse', value);
    }
}
```

This is the main Vue instance function `toggleHouse()` in **app.js**:

```
Vue.component('property-house', require('./components/PropertyHouseComponent.vue'));
...
toggleHouse: function() { <-- this method is being completely ignored
    if(value) {
        this.csHouse = value;
    }
}
```

Just in case you think "you are not passing `value` to the function, so it won't change anything, I tried with `console.log()`. But is not my concern right now (I think)

And finally, this is the HTML part:

```
<property-house :value="true"></property-house>
```

And then it renders in the DOM correcly:
[image: render]

So, what am I doing wrong this time and what I should do in order to call `toggleHouse` from inside the component? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to *listen* for an event. Emitting an event is not the same as calling a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't emit functions. You emit events.

You need to listen for the `toggleHouse` event, and I would additionally recommend never using camel cased event names (for reasons beyond the scope of this answer).

Let's assume you change to use `toggle-house` instead.

```
this.$emit('toggle-house', value)
```

Where you use the `property-house` should look like this

```
<property-house :value="true" @toggle-house="toggleHouse"></property-house>
```

Note the `@toggle-house`. This is the shortcut method for listening to an event in Vue; you could also use the full syntax, `v-on:toggle-house="toggleHouse"`.

In either case (using `@toggle-house` or `v-on:toggle-house`) a listener is set up that listens for the `toggle-house` event you are emitting from the child component that calls the `toggleHouse` method when the event occurs.

Here is a very rudimentary example.

```js
console.clear()

Vue.component("property-house", {
  template: `
    <div>
      <button @click="$emit('toggle-house', 'Clicked the button')">Click Me</button>
    </div>`
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {
    toggleHouse(message){
      alert(message)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <property-house @toggle-house="toggleHouse"></property-house>
 </div>
```

Comment: @Maramal When you say "kinda" working I suspect the issue is you did not specify an argument for `toggleHouse` in your question code. It should look like `toggleHouse: function(someParameter) {...}` where `someParameter` will become the value that you emitted (in your case either `this.data` or `value`).

Comment: You suspected right, I've changed it before posting the question and then I've changed it again and it worked. My apologies for the "kinda" working. I's working.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change the strategy since `@click="callFunc"` was taking the opposite checkbox value, I guess, that event was fired before changing the `v-model="data"`.

Therefore my new components look like this:

```
<template>
    <fieldset class="form-group col-md">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input
                class="form-check-input"
                type="checkbox"
                id="house"
                name="house"
                v-model="data">
            <label
                for="house"
                class="form-check-label"
            >House</label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</template>

<script>
    module.exports = {
        props: {
            value: {
                type: Boolean,
                required: false
            }
        },
        data: function() {
            return {
                data: false
            }
        },
        created: function() {
            if(this.value) {
                this.data = this.value;
            }
        },
        watch: {
            data: function(value) {
                this.$emit('callback', value);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```